# Style css input file Firefox (working on chrome too)

Tags: html, css, file, input, upload

I'm working on an upload page where I cannot use jquery and bootstrap.
On Chrome I used this code css code to solve my problem

```
.btn-file-upload{
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
    height: 40px;
}

.btn-file-upload:after{
   content:  attr(value);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;    
   width: 99%;
   background: white;
   color: black;
   border:1px solid rgb(0, 0, 126);
   border-radius: 2px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 1.7;
   overflow: visible;
}


<input type="file" name="theFile" size="60" value="label" onkeypress="javascript:return false;" onchange="changeFileName()" class="btn-file-upload">
```

How can I make it work on firefox too without breaking the chrome version?
Also, there is a way to make the input file drag&drop on Internet Explorer too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some hours of trial&error I actually found a real solution to this problem

First I modified the css without the after

```
.btn-file-upload{
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 200px;
   background: white;
   color: black;
   border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 126);
   border-radius: 2px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 1.7;
   overflow: visible;
   height: 40px;
}
```

Second I used a button+input instead of input to be able to set a custom message

```
<button id="inputdrop" onclick="return document.getElementById('getFile').click();return false;" onkeypress="javascript:return false;"  class="btn-file-upload">Label</button>
<input size='60' style='width: 187px;display:none' type='file' name="theFile" id="getFile" onchange="changeFileName()">
<span id="filename" class="Testo">No file selected</span>
```

Finally I used some js to be able to drag&drop (the changefilename was already working)

```
function changeFileName(){
    document.getElementById("filename").innerText = code to get file name in struts;
}


//code here go on the onload
document.getElementById("inputdrop").ondragover = document.getElementById("inputdrop").ondragenter = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
};

document.getElementById("inputdrop").ondrop = function(evt) {
  document.getElementById("getFile").files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
  changeFileName();
  evt.preventDefault();
};
```

The only limitation is that this is not working on Internet Explorer and the old Edge... But, at least, this works on both chrome and firefox and the new edge.